# "Once" in the beginning of the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, past-participles

I have seen sentence structures like the following:

> Once opened, the chicken broth is good for 2 days.

My two questions:

1. what tense should be used after *once*? past, or the past participle? So, which one is correct:

   > Once drunk, the bottle should be disposed of properly.

   or

   > Once drank, the bottle should be disposed of properly.

?

2. Can such a sentence structure be used in formal contexts?

Comment: There is an error in your sentences that unintentionally makes them very funny.  The original sentence is about the chicken broth: "Once opened, the chicken broth..." but your sentences are about *you*: "Once drunk, you..."  This actually says that once you are drunk, you should dispose of the bottle!  A more accurate phrasing would be "Once drunk, *the bottle* should (etc.)"  But don't worry; even many native speakers make this kind of mistake.

Comment: @stangdon Haha, this was actually pretty funny, too bad that it's fixed now and the future readers will be deprived of a good laugh :)

Comment: It's still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words "opened" and "drunk" here are functioning like adjectives; they describe the state of the broth/bottle. For this purpose, use the past participle. It's the same as in the sentence:

> That seat was *taken*.

And yes, this structure is OK to use in formal contexts.